# Wireshark - Identification: 0x0000 (0) of TTL package

Tags: networking, protocols, wireshark

I use wireshark to check the transport in the net.

I look on package which send to me from other computer (Time-to-live exceeded package).

When I look at the internet protocol section, I recognize that most of the package are with `Identification: 0x0000 (0)`. Why this happen, and what the meaning of it?

Comment: Do you mean 'packet' where you say 'package'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's used for fragmentation. If you split a packet, all its fragments will contain the same identification. So the receiver can then know to which packet the fragment belongs.

Since fragmentation is generally avoided, you'll generally see Identification = 0. However, I do remember something about some stacks using it for other experimental purposes.

#### EDIT for berkay

> When I look at the internet protocol section, I recognize that most of
> the package are with Identification: 0x0000 (0). Why this happen, and
> what the meaning of it

Comment: what do you mean by: "Since fragmentation is generally avoided, you'll generally see Identification = 0"? It means that the package doesn't ariive to it destination? Because as I know, all fragments will contain the same identification, but this identification != 0.

Comment: @cnicutar, i guess you are confused about TTL.How TLL helps destination to identify packet fragments belong to.

Comment: @berkay Why do you think that ? I have quoted the op. Try to read the answer and the question again. If you're careful, you'll notice I never mentioned `TTL`.